# How to detect if SD card is corrupted using metadata Checksum?

Tags: pi-2, corrupt

I have enabled metadata checksum in my Rpi 2 using [this](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=332769). Is there any way to use this metadata checksum to detect if the sd card is corrupted?

Answer (score 1):

The metadata checksum is used automatically every time you access the filesystem. If you access a file with a corrupted metadata, the filesystem will (typically) remount as read-only, and the system will tell you to run a filesystem check. Such check will also typically be triggered automatically upon reboot.

If you suspect corruption, you can run `fsck` manually to anticipate automatic detection.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: I have two questions
1. If the checksum fails will it write anything in a log file like var/log/syslog?
2. I thought fsck does not verify the checksum. Will fsck be enough to detect the file corruption?

Comment: Check what `fsck` does! Type `man fsck`

Comment: @Saugat `fsck` will have to check metadata CRCs, in fact, if you install an older `fsck` which doesn't understand `metadata_csum`, it won't be able to work at all: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=213125

Comment: @Saugat and just to clarify, metadata checksums protect **metadata**, *not* the file contents. If you need data checksums, you'll need to use a filesystem which supports them, e.g. ZFS or BTRFS.